# Angle between Two Lines in 3D Space

Tags: geometry

Since my two lines are orthogonal (one in y-z plane and one in y-x), I KNOW there's a (probably simple) formula for the calculation I need, but somehow I haven't been able to find it. Equations of the two lines

y = .384z (or, 22.6 degrees)

y = -3.864x (or -75 degrees)

Obviously, they intersect at the origin. I want the angle as measured in the plane defined by these two lines.

Comment: You've given two planes, not two lines.

Comment: @J.M. Each line has an additional equation implied by `one in y-z plane and one in y-x`.

Comment: In that case, @dxiv, the direction cosines should now be easy to compute, no?

Comment: Depending on context and background, you may either construct a rectangular parallelepiped with a vertex at the origin and two others on the given lines, then resolve the triangle formed by those 3 vertices. Or, choose a couple of vectors along the two lines, then calculate the angle between them.

Comment: The dot product of two unit vectors in the directions of these lines will give you the cosine of the angle between them.

Answer (score 3):

Take a point $A$ on the first line and a point $B$ on the second line. For instance:
$$
A=(0,0.384,1);\quad B=(1,-0.3864,0).
$$
To find the angle $\theta=\angle AOB$ between lines, you can choose among several different ways. If you are comfortable with the cosine rule, you can for instance apply it to triangle $ABO$ (where $O=(0,0,0)$):
$$
AB^2=OA^2+OB^2-2OA\cdot OB\cos\theta
$$
and solve for $\cos\theta$.

Or you may exploit the definition of dot product:
$$
\vec{OA}\cdot\vec{OB}=OA\cdot OB\cos\theta.
$$